# How to get each digit of a template integral type in its native base?

Tags: c++, c++20

I am working on an implementation of Radix sort for arrays of integral types. Using the `numeric_limits` functions provided by the standard library, I am able to learn about the native base representation of any given integral type using `numeric_limits::radix`, and the maximum amount of digits in that base that the type can hold using `numeric_limits::digits`. In order to implement radix sort optimally, I need to extract the value of each of those digits in turn for each of the elements of the array. Is there some standard, or at least common, way to do this? In case it matters, I am using C++20 and do not care about backwards compatibility with older revisions of the standard, only maximum interoperability with other C++20 code.

Comment: All fundamental integral types have radix 2 so it all sounds kind of confused. You need a way to get all bits of integral value?

Comment: All the fundamental integral types have radix 2, but I also want to be compatible with say, a struct decimal type that uses base 10 (obviously fundamentally it would still be binary at the lowest level, but a custom data type might use binary to represent decimal digits, an example that comes to mind is Python's Decimal type)

Comment: The maximum number of base digits is the floor of log(max v)/log(base).

Comment: @Rilazy: "*a struct decimal type that uses base 10*" What operations do you expect this type to provide? Would it have the full range of integer operations through operator overloading? And would they act like regular integer operations?

Comment: I'm making a library (mostly as a learning exercise) to perform various kinds of operations on arrays of integers. Ideally I'd like to make as few assumptions as possible about the type; my hope is that there's some standard or common way to get the digits of an integral type, so that I don't need to rely on modulus and division and make my users (future self) implement those functions, especially where there might be a faster way to do the same thing with knowledge of the underlying representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate through the digits of the number `number` expressed with `radix` radix, in order from least-to-greatest significant digits, then a loop like the following would work. This loop assumes that `number` is a type that supports division and modulus, and that these operations are purely integer operations (fractions are removed):

```
auto curr_val = number; //Copy the number, since we're going to modify it.
while(curr_val != 0)
{
  auto curr_digit = curr_val % radix;
  curr_val = curr_val / radix; //Integer division.
}
```

Note that this works regardless of the representation of `number` in whatever internal representation the type uses. So even if `numeric_limits<int>::radix` is 2, this will work for iterating through the way `number` would be represented in base-10.

Comment: While this does sort of answer my question as I asked it, what I was more looking for was a way to let the type define how the digit is found; since there will often be a faster way to determine what the ith digit of n is than to compute (n / (radix ^ i)) % radix. For example, with the built in types it's significantly faster to compute a bitshift and bitwise AND than a division by 2^i and a modulus (disregarding compiler optimizations which would likely generate the same code for both; custom types don't have that luxury).

Comment: @Rilazy: That would basically involve creating a digit-range interface for the types that people can implement for their user-defined types.

Answer (score -1):

If you are only working with integer type that uses radix 2, you can use `bitset` to extract each digit:

```cpp
auto i = 384762132;
std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<decltype(i)>::digits> b(i);
std::cout << b;     // 0010110111011110000000100010100
std::cout << b[4];  // 1(prints 4th 0-indexed lsb)
```